# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource CORS error only for certain endpoints - React/DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, cors, django-cors-headers

I'm getting the following CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://___backend.herokuapp.com/api/tickets/21/' from origin 'http://___frontend.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I believe all my django-cors-header settings are correct:

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = False
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["https://____frontend.herokuapp.com"]
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://____frontend.herokuapp.com"]
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = DEFAULT_HEADERS #this list includes Access-Control-Allow-Origin

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]
```

The cors headers middleware is on top of the list and it's in installed apps.

The weird part is that I'm only getting this error for 2 endpoints even though I'm using the exact same request options on the frontend:

```
const requestOptions = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                }
            }
```

I'm really confused as to how API calls to other endpoints can work fine but not for these 2. Another weird part is that once I get the CORS error for the 2 endpoints and then try to signout for example, I get the same error from that endpoint. If I don't try to access the 2 troublesome endpoints beforehand the signout endpoint works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure, but that may be due to some caching issue. In the responses, do you see `Vary: Origin`?

Comment: Yes, Vary: Origin is in the response. What issue would that imply?

Comment: Is it present in the response when CORS fails as well?

Comment: For the CORS fails it's Vary: Origin and for the successful calls it's Vary: Accept, Origin

Comment: What is the value of `DEFAULT_HEADERS`? Does it include `Content-Type` and `Authorization`? By the way, listing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is pointless.